# How to prevent WPF's ContentControl from reusing DataTemplates?

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol, ui-virtualization

I stumbled upon the famous `TabControl` virtuality problem. I thought of replacing the `TabControl` with styled list (to present tabs) and `ContentControl` (to present content of a tab). However, it seems like `ContentControl` has the same behavior of reusing `DataTemplates` if two contents share their type.

Is there a way to force `ContentControl` to instantiate separate `DataTemplates` for all displayed items?

---

**Edit:** Example

Say, that we have the following UserControl acting as DataTemplate for document view model:

DocumentControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlTemplateProblem.DocumentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlTemplateProblem"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded"
             x:Name="Main">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Main, Path=StoredIndex}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

DocumentControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ControlTemplateProblem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DocumentControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DocumentControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool initialized = false;
        private string storedIndex;

        public DocumentControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StoredIndex = ((ItemViewModel)DataContext).Index;
        }

        private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StoredIndex = "(detached)";
        }

        public string StoredIndex
        {
            get => storedIndex;
            set
            {
                storedIndex = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StoredIndex)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Main window's view model looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ControlTemplateProblem
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ItemViewModel selectedItem;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            selectedItem = Items.First();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> {
            new ItemViewModel(),
            new ItemViewModel(),
            new ItemViewModel()
        };

        public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ControlTemplateProblem.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlTemplateProblem"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                    <local:DocumentControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I expect the document to display two equal indices - one coming directly from document's viewmodel and second extracted from the document's viewmodel by the control (this is *simulation* of performing some initializations on the control upon attaching viewmodel). After starting the application and choosing different items will yield always ( 0) and the 0 is because control was initialized only once and ContentControl reuses the DataTemplate.

Alternative question to the one I asked would be: how to **reliably** call code *just after* DataContext was set and *just before* DataContext is about to change? Then I'd be able to (again) *reliaby* initialize and deinitialize visuals for the specific viewmodel.

Comment: Please provide an example of how the templates are shared and what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: @mm8, here you go.

Comment: Where is the `ContentControl` in your example...? It's pretty central to the issue, isn't it?

Comment: @mm8, I missed the MainWindow.xaml, added.

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found that by setting the x:Shared attribute of the DataTemplate to false, a new instance of my view would be created for each viewmodel.  According to the [documentation for x:Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute), it can only be applied in a ResourceDictionary, however, so you might have to change your view code to something like:

```
<Window x:Class="ControlTemplateProblem.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlTemplateProblem"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
            <local:DocumentControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

If @TomM's answer didn't work for you, add the `x:Shared="False"` attribute to your `DataTemplate` and then *also* add a dummy `DataTemplateSelector` whose `SelectTemplate` method always returns `null` to the `ContentControl`'s `ContentTemplateSelector` property. This will prevent it from reusing DataTemplate instances in the fashion described without affecting any other functionality.

#### Why does this work?

Whether a `ContentControl` reuses DataTemplate instances is based on the value of `mismatch` computed in [`ContentPresenter.OnContentChanged`](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/89d172db0b7a192de720c6cfba5e28a1e7d46123/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs#L179). If `mismatch` is `false` the current template will be reused, otherwise it will be recreated. In the case of template selection based on `DataType`, the method reaches [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/89d172db0b7a192de720c6cfba5e28a1e7d46123/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs#L216) which sets `mismatch` to `true` iff the old and new `Content` values have different types, matching the behavior you observed. However, if a `ContentTemplateSelector` is present, `mismatch` is unconditionally set to `true` on [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/89d172db0b7a192de720c6cfba5e28a1e7d46123/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs#L199).

As for the dummy `DataTemplateSelector`, it doesn't break anything because [`ContentPresenter.ChooseTemplate`](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/89d172db0b7a192de720c6cfba5e28a1e7d46123/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs#L527) falls back to a (private) `DefaultTemplateSelector` if `ContentTemplateSelector` is null *or* if it returns null - so you'll get the same template selection algorithm as with no `DataTemplateSelector` at all.

If `x:Shared` is not false, the above is all still true, but it does not achieve the desired effect because the `DataTemplate` is cached at a lower level of the system.